# Mongoose getter is getting undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm storing a price value in my Mongoose schema according to the answer from [how should i store a price in mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304129/how-should-i-store-a-price-in-mongoose)

I have the following code in my schema definition:

```
 price: {
        value: {
            type: Number,
            get: getPrice,
            set: setPrice,
            min: 0
        },
        currency: {
            type: String,
            default: 'PLN',
            trim: true,
            enum: ['PLN', 'EUR']
        }
},
```

and my get function:

```
function getPrice(num){
    return (num/100).toFixed(2);
}
```

However, whenever this getter function is called I can see that the num parameter in undefined.

Do you know what might be the reason for that? And how could I fix this?

Comment: Where do you have the `getPrice` function?

Comment: In the same file as the schema definition, but outside the definition itself.

Comment: Your getter function will still be called for docs that don't have that field.  In that case `num` will be `undefined`.  Might that be what you're seeing?

Comment: It's not the case. I checked it for the documents which have price value already set.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem. Every time I fetch an object, the getter method runs like 4 times, I don't know why, but also, I am getting undefined.. for some of those 4 calls.

Answer (score 1):

Add a default of zero for value. Also, mongoose is notoriously bad about subdocuments that are not inside an array, which may be causing this problem.

```
    value: {
        type: Number,
        get: getPrice,
        set: setPrice,
        min: 0,
        default: 0
    },
```

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Still num in getPrice function is set to undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If getter/setters give you problems with mongoose models, use the native [static methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) in mongoose schemas:

```
mySchema.static('getPrice', function(){
    //'this' in the context means a document that shares the schema
    return (this.price.value/100).toString(2); 
});
```

You can invoke the method in any document that have said schema:

```
var myPrice = oneMongooseDocument.getPrice();
```

Is a very clean approach.