# Mongoose does not save Numbers as decimals

Tags: javascript, mongoose

What I'm trying to save on my DB are Numbers ending with `.nn`.

Model:

```
var invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  n: { type: String, default: '' },
  note: { type: String, default: '' },
  customer: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    address: { type: String, default: '' }
  },
  values: [{
    quantity: Number,
    pu: { type: Number },
    service: String,
    description: String,
    tva: Number,
    tva10: { type: Number },
    tva20: { type: Number },
    montantHT: { type: Number },
    totalTTC: { type: Number }
  }]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Data I'm passing for `pu`, `tva10`, `tva20`, `montantHT`, `totalTTC` is this (checked on logs):

```
2835.00
2577.27
0
257.73
189.00
```

Data saved on MongoDB is this:

```
2835
2577.270000
0
257.730000
189
```

What I tried so far is to add:

```
montantHT: { type: Number, set: toDecimal }

---

function toDecimal (val) { return parseFloat(val.toFixed(2)); }
```

Nothing happen, it simply continue to return what it wish...

I also tried to add currency:

```
montantHT: { type: Number, currency: "EUR" }
```

Even here, nothing happen...

How can I simply save what I pass or how can I convert my `Number` to end with `.nn`?

**EDIT:**

For those people that not knowing how to answer a question prefer to vote for closing and search for other similar question (don't you have nothing else to do?):

Following those link to the "similar" question (that I already visited before posting) do nothing. It simply return my numbers multiplied by 100.
What I need is to format my Numbers like: 100.00, 100.35, etc... not 100 or 100.823768.

Can someone answer how to save those kind of Double in MongoDB? Thanks

Comment: IMHO this hasn't to do with mongodb, because it saves values as they come. So if you pass in a double like 1337.0 - it is saved as a double.

Comment: Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-double - this should to the trick, or give the required information.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304129/how-should-i-store-a-price-in-mongoose

Comment: The other clarification is that from a MongoDB perspective, all of these are actually BSON Double, but it is just that no arbitary "precision" is actually stored and nor will it be for values such as `2835.00`. The "Money" type debate has been around for years. There is even an official manual section [Model Monetary Data](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/) that has some perspectives on this.